# Solving Minimization with Integar programming

Tags: python, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming, operations-research

I am asked to solve the following problem:

## The problem:

You were asked to repair a farm house with sheets of plywood.

- You were given **thirty sheets of plywood**. (each size = 10ft x 10ft)
- The house requires **20 circles** (radius = 2.5ft ) and **15 rectangles** (size = 6ft x 4ft)
- It costs **20 dollars to cut a circle** and **15 dollars to cut a rectange**. And there are **three ways** to cut the sheets as shown below:

Here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOomz.png

Basically,

1st way: cutting 4 circles out of 1 sheet

2nd way: cutting 4 rectangles out of 1 sheet

3rd way: cutting 2cicles and 1 rectangle out of 1 sheet

(I set these into x,y,z:numbers of sheets cut in the way)

- You can also buy **1 single circle with 45 dollars** and **1 rectangle with 30 dollars**.
- You **CANNOT waste more than 30%** of the material. (Assuming total unused area <= 30%)

## Here is how I solve the problem:

x,y,z = number of sheets cut in the ways shown above

Objective function:

**M = 80x+60y+55z**

Constrants:

**1. 4x+2z<=20**

**2. 4y+z<=15**

**3. x+y+z<=30**

**4. 0.215x+0.04y+0.367z<=0.3(x+y+z)**

It seems that I am getting all zero but I cannot figure out how to set the constraints.

I am asked to solve this with ORtools python.

But it doesn't make any sense to do it with the incorrect equations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the first two constraints wrong, should be greater than.

Here a model where also the possibility to buy separate circles (`c`) and rectangles (`r`) have been included:

```
M = 80x+60y+55z+45c+30r
```

Constraints:

```
1. 4x+2z+c >= 20

2. 4y+z+r >= 15

3. x+y+z <= 30

4. 0.215x+0.04y+0.367z <= 0.3(x+y+z)

5. x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, c >= 0, r >= 0
```

gives:

```
M=640, x=5, y=4, z=0, c=0, r=0
```

Comment: thanks!u saved my day! but it seems that x+y+z should be <= 30, otherwise, it will give a different answer

Comment: sorry my mistake, will fix it